# can't get result object in doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, dql

I got DQL like this:

```
$sql =$qb->select('login,id')
->from('Cusomter','c')
->where('c.login = :login')
->setParameter('login',$login);
$rs = $sql->getQuery()->getResult();
```

I want the result would return  as object with 2 properties: Login,id.
Is there anyway i can do that? I tried `CustomHydrator` but it won't work out.
this is my CustomHydrator:

```
namespace Hydrator;

use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\AbstractHydrator;

class CustomHydrator extends AbstractHydrator
{
   protected function hydrateAllData()
   {
    return $this->_stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   }
}
```

Then i added `$em->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode('CustomHydrator', 'Hydrator\CustomHydrator');`
and run :`$rs = $sql->getQuery()->getResult('CustomHydrator');`

Comment: And what object do you get instead?

Comment: i got result as array

Comment: Please remove `->select('login,id')` from query.

Comment: you can always use getSQL() from Doctrine to see what is you SQL query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about this. If this is a query that you need to reuse, then Doctrine custom hydrators is perhaps the best approach. If not, you could simply cast the result to an object.

If you need a single result:

```
$sql =$qb->select('c.login, c.id')
    ->from('Cusomter','c')
    ->where('c.login = :login')
    ->setParameter('login', $login);
$rs = (object) $sql->getQuery()->getSingleResult();
```

If you need to return an array of objects (i.e. multiple result items), then you could just cast each result:

```
$sql =$qb->select('c.login, c.id')
    ->from('Cusomter','c')
    ->where('c.login = :login')
    ->setParameter('login', $login);

$rs_new = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (object) $value;
}, $sql->getQuery()->getResult());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Better way to use Entity as result http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#creating-an-entity-class
2. As I understand, you need just one result, so use next code inside repository:

   $rs = $this->findOneBy(['login' => $login]);